# Filter based on a string and count number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have recently started working with VBA and I have to filter a column with string 'NEWV' and to count number of rows that end after that filtering,Currently am using the below code but that doesnt seem to work,

```
ByrNbr = Watchlist.Range("B" & i).Value

LookFor = ByrNbr

Set Age_rng = Total.Sheets("Counts").Range("A:S")

If Total.Sheets("Counts").Range("G:G").Value = "NEWV" Then

 .Range("L27").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Age_rng, Range("A:A"))

End If
```

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve. Try using `Age_rng,Range("A2").Value` but I'm just guessing.

Comment: you cannot test a multi-cell range to one value `Total.Sheets("Counts").Range("G:G").Value = "NEWV"` will cause an error.  You will need to loop through the range and test each cell separately.

Comment: @DavidG. I have to count number of rows which has NEWV string in G column

Comment: @ScottCraner How do I do that ? and the last row number  is not the same all  the time, It keeps changing

Comment: You need to use the countif function.  Is the "NEWV" the whole string in the cell or just part of the string in the cell?

Comment: Yes NEWV is the entire string and I am using Countif but it doesnt seem to work with the range am specifying,can you check my code?

Comment: Why are you counting Age_rng equal to A2?  Your explanation doesn't match your code.  Are you counting NEWV in column G or A2 in named range Age_rng?

Comment: @mooseman I am first filtering the column G for NEWV string and count the COLUMN A after filtering and putting that count value in L27.On top of this all this is being filtered for each buyer for which am using Lookfor = Byrnbr

Comment: no where in your code are you filtering.

Comment: But it sounds like you want COUNTIFS with multiple conditions.

Comment: @mooseman Sorry it is a entire page coding which I have written and facing problems in this area,I just picked the area where I was having problems.I have now edited the code which I posted to include few more lines where am filtering for ByrNbr

Comment: So you want a count of rows if Column B = ByrNbr and Column G = NEWV.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what am trying to achieve @mooseman

Comment: @mooseman I have another question,If I have to add another condition say,I have to subtract (today's date - Column(I:I) ) < 91 on top of those 2 conditions how do I do that? Now I have 3 conditions and have to count number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what workbook and worksheet these ranges are on, but you could use something like this, just have to clarify where each range resides.

```
ByrNbr = Watchlist.Range("B" & i).Value
     Worksheets(???).Range("L27").Value =WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Watchlist.Range("B:B" ), ByrNbr, 
    Watchlist.Range("G:G"), "NEWV")
```

Comment: I have another question,If I have to add another condition say,I have to subtract (today's date - Column(I:I) ) < 91 on top of those 2 conditions how do I do that? Now I have 3 conditions and have to count number of rows.

Comment: Add another criteria like watchlist.range(I:I),"<Date -91"

Comment: No, (Date - I:I )should be less than or equal to 91

Comment: watchlist.range(I:I),"<=Date -91", should be the same thing mathematically.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I have another question. I have 2 workbooks A & B.The workbooks are already defined.I have an issue with part of my code where I am trying to compare column A from workbook A and Column D from Workbook B. If it matches then I want to copy corresponding column B to Workbook column E.

Comment: That's a different question and one that has been asked here already.  Search for that for some answers

Answer (score 0):

Try testing this line without the `If` statement

```
Range("L27").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Age_rng,"NEWV")
```

Comment: This works if I just want to count NEWV string, but I have to match that with Buyer nbr where am giving Lookfor = Byrnbr

Comment: Then, your question and goal is still not clear. There are several attempts to help you, but you are not providing enough information.

Comment: This is how the code of mine goes,ByrNbr = Watchlist.Range("B" & i).Value

LookFor = ByrNbr

Set Age_rng = Total.Sheets("Counts").Range("A:S")

If Total.Sheets("Counts").Range("G:G").Value = "NEWV" Then
        
 .Range("L27").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Age_rng, Range("A:A"))
        
End If

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub formulatest()

MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheet1.Range("B13:B16"), Sheet1.Range("C12").Value, Sheet1.Range("G13:G16"), Sheet1.Range("D12").Value)
'~~Returns 2

End Sub
```